# 2D array declaration in Objective-C++ error

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c

I'm developing an iOS application with latest SDK.

I want to create a `int [][]` in Objective-C++ but I don't know how to do it:

This is piece of `MyClass.mm`:

```
static const int MAX_NUM_DETECTIONS = 10;
static const int PATCH_SIZE = 100;

@interface MyClass ()
{
    int[MAX_NUM_DETECTIONS][PATCH_SIZE*PATCH_SIZE] _results;
}

@end
```

That line of code generate this two errors:

Expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers.
Expected ';' at end of declaration list

I get the error under `_` character.

**How can I declare and initialize that 2D array?**

Comment: As far I know, **Objective-C++** `must be *.mm` files `not *.m`

Comment: @rokimoki He could be overriding that `.m` file to compile as Objective-C++.

Comment: Probably, but it's information that he could doesn't know, that's why I only commented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put the `[][]` brackets after the variable name:

eg:

```
int multiArr[3][4];
```

Comment: And then, Is this var initialized or do I have to do anything else?

Comment: If you know C/C++, it'd be the same way, but the array it's only declared, not initialized.

Answer (score 4):

You need

```
int _results[MAX_NUM_DETECTIONS][PATCH_SIZE*PATCH_SIZE] ;
```

Answer (score 1):

right way of declaring the 2d array is two put two square brackets `[][]` after the variable name, so in your case it would be

```
int  _results[MAX_NUM_DETECTIONS][PATCH_SIZE*PATCH_SIZE];
```